# How can I skip a Jenkins pipeline step with sleep inside?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins pipeline with couple of stages, one in the middle contains a "security" sleep, so I have time to double-check deployment from previous stages.

```
stage('Wait 15 minutes') {
  steps {
  sleep 900
  }
}
```

Is there any way how I could potentially manually skip this stage to speed up the pipeline when I find all previous stages are stable?

Answer (score 0):

There you go, userInput step can take your sleep time and you can use it in a later sleep command, which allows also to type 0, which means no waiting time.

```
node{
            // Get the input
            def userInput = input(
                    id: 'sleeptime', message: 'Enter sleep time.',
                    parameters: [
                            string(defaultValue: "10",
                                    description: 'time to sleep',
                                    name: 'sleeptime'),
                    ])

            sleep userInput.sleeptime
```

}

You could also automatically save the state of previous steps in a variable, to not have so much manual interaction. Thats why Continuous Integration should be done. With a simple if condition you could then check if your previous steps of deployment were okay and proceed based on this.